# Z3 FP logic: produces unexpected model

Tags: z3

For this problem: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/YNBG

Z3 produces the model:

```
sat
((s0 FP!val!0))
```

I was expecting to see a true number as the model. It's almost as if it's treating `FP` as an uninterpreted sort for this case. Is there a way to get Z3 to produce a real number here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. Indeed, there was a bug in the model completion for FPA. The fix is already available in the unstable branch at [Codeplex](http://z3.codeplex.com).

Note that == (floating point equal) with NaN is always false, i.e., in this example, any `s0` satisfies the formula. Such values are now correctly omitted at all (in get-model) or the model is completed with a NaN (for get-value or generally when model completion is enabled).